# Connect two maya on local network

Tags: maya, maya-api

How to connect two maya in local area network.

For example.

2 users open [maya](http://www.autodesk.in/products/maya/overview) software in different computers in local area network
and connect there maya session by python [commandPort](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/commandPort.html).

The final goal is
both user can edit a same model at same time.
when user 1 move vertex or faces.. etc these changes should live display in the view port of other user and vice versa.

Comment: I think you are looking for a collaboration tool which works between maya. same as google Docs where multiple users can edit the same document in same time. google is using operational transformation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation . to make this possible.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation of the `commandPort` command.

Brief answer for an unclear question.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. my question is very simple. and I think the answer might be complicated . what is not clear to you..?

Answer (score 2):

The command port will work to let one instance of maya respond to commands issued by another. However maya's UI is essentially single-threaded: if one user is running a script the other is locked out until it executes to completion.  So there's not really 'collaborative' editing in that sense. Also, the commandPort connections are text only: it's like ssh into a maya session.

If you want both users to see and edit the model, you probably want a multi-user screen sharing tool -- but that's likely to be slow.